# Extra data is not passing through gallery intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a data from my gallery intent but in onActivityResult I'm getting extras value null. Here is how I am using putExtra

```
     val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        galleryIntent.putExtra("position", position)

        if(galleryIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.packageManager) != null) {
            (mContext as Activity).startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select image"),
                GRID_IMAGE_GALLERY
            )
        }
```

I am not sure if we can pass extras with implicit intent, if there is any way please tell me how can I pass the extra data here.

Comment: You can pass data to the Camera app. But the Camera app will not pass that data back to your app in onActivityResult. It's a pitty.

Comment: okay... means my extra data is getting destroyed after resolving the galleryIntent !

Answer (score 1):

`putExtra()` is for sending data to another app. There is no requirement for that other app to do anything with any extras that you send. In particular, there is no requirement for that other app to somehow send those extras back to you.

> I am not sure if we can pass extras with implicit intent

Yes, you can. However, you are assuming that you will *receive* those extras in some form of response, and that is incorrect.

Comment: and getting any response from the intent is not possible right!